# Retrofit POST with custom body param names

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I'm consuming an API which has "private" as a param on the body on some POST action.

```
@PATCH("/users/{facebookId}/plan/{myPlanId}")
void updatePlan(@Path("facebookId") String facebookId, @Path("myPlanId") Integer myPlanId, @Body PlanParamUpdate param, Callback<Object> callback);
```

And the body param should be like this

```
public class PlanParamUpdate {

  public boolean private;

}
```

Obviously this is a reserved word... So, How can I define this to use this object.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Rename your field to `isPrivate` and annotate it with `@SerializedName("private")` if you're using GSON, or `@JsonProperty("private")` if you're using Jackson.